# Query S3 Bucket With Amazon Athena and modify values

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have an S3 bucket with 500 csv files that are identical except for the number values in each file.

[image: csv template]

How do I write query that grabs `dividendsPaid` and make it positive for each file and send that back to s3?

Comment: What do you mean by "send that back to s3"? Do you want to _overwrite_ the existing files, or store a _new_ set of files with the updated information?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Athena is a **query engine** that can perform queries on objects stored in Amazon S3. It **cannot modify files in an S3 bucket**. If you want to modify those input files in-place, then you'll need to find another way to do it.

However, it is possible for Amazon Athena to **create a new table** with the output files stored in a different location. You could use the existing files as *input* and then store new files as *output*.

The basic steps are:

- Create a table definition (DDL) for the *existing* data (I would recommend using an AWS Glue crawler to do this for you)
- Use `CREATE TABLE AS` to select data from the table and write it to a different `location` in S3. The command can include an SQL `SELECT` statement to modify the data (changing the negatives).

See: [Creating a table from query results (CTAS) - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html)